# jvm monitor no provider installed/cannot attach to 64-bit process error despite jvm FAQ solution

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

So I can't get jvm monitor to run. I have set eclipse (Mars) to start with the -vm option for the jdk1.8.0_60, the same I set in jvm preferences.

However on 32-bit eclipse I get the error "cannot attach to a 64 bit process" (despite I downloaded x86 Java version), and on 64-bit eclipse I get the error message "no providers installed", which the jvm monitor FAQ says are both fixed by what I did (setting Eclipse to use same jdk and same 32/64-bit)...